# Notepad++ using regex to store variable

Tags: regex, notepad++

I tried googling extensively to figure this out, but was having trouble.

I'm just trying to do something simple.

```
C.var1 = 0.1;
```

I just want to add curly braces around the 0.1, so `C.var1 = {0.1};`. (Spaces don't matter).

I know that () parentheses in notepad++'s regex editor are how you store variables, but I can't find much syntax documentation online...

I can use the regex =[ ]+ to match the equal signs and spaces up to the 0, and I was hoping that the regex =[ ]+(.+); would store the string between "= " and the semicolon ; inside the variable \1, but it just says not found.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `=[ ]+(.+);` finds the string. Use `(= *)(.+);` and replace with `$1{$2};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `=\h*\K([^;]+)`
- Replace with: {$1}`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
=           # equal sign
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(           # start capture group 1
  [^;]+     # 1 or more any character that is not semi colon
)           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the value)
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]